# how to add texture to the arms when there is no arm collection

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing, collections

[image]

I'm trying to add a the arm/leg texture to my guy that i pulled from source via crowbar and VTFedit software to my guy in the image but there is no arm leg collection.

Does anyone know how to correct this issue?

[image]

Comment: Hello what do you mean by "there is no arm collection"? Materials have nothing to do with collections, could you please elaborate?

Comment: okay...when i pulled another model a while ago...there were two segments...the arms/leg and the body...i could easily add the arm/leg textures in the shader editor and the same with the body...however when im doing this one...there just body and the body texture is alrady applied and if i try to apply the arm/leg texture it puts it where the body is, NOT where the arm/leg texture is.

Comment: I would stronlgy suggest you watch some beginner tutorials on materials and texturing, because as @moonboots said, materials have nothing to do with collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into the *Material* panel, select the material called *leg* and click on *Select*, you'll see that the material is assigned to the legs and arms:

[image]

If you want to assign another material to a part of the body, select the faces in the 3D view (use <kbd>L</kbd> to select a mesh), choose the material in the list and click on *Assign*:

[image]